# Obtener link en ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo un problema con obtener un **link** en un servicio de **ruby**, desde el **html** puedo obtener el **link** de la siguiente forma:

```
<%=organization_task_edit_form_path(@organization)%>
```

Pero necesito obtener el link en un servicio **(.rb)** y al intentar con

```
 organization_task_edit_form_path(@organization)
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> undefined method `organization_task_edit_form_path'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los *helpers* para crear rutas únicamente están disponibles en las vistas y controladores, pero puedes utilizarlos en cualquier otro archivo si explícitamente los solicitas dentro de la clase; por ejemplo:

```
class MyService
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def initialize
    @organization = # ...
  end

  def method_with_link
    # ...
    organization_task_edit_form_path(@organization)
  end
end
```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación y solución, me resultó perfectamente!!